# Not able to deploy to Google App Engine Managed VM

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud

When I try to deploy my node app on GAE I get this error (app ID stripped):

```
WARNING: If this is your first deployment, please try again.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [404]:
Not Found Unexpected HTTP status 404.
This application does not exist (app_id=u'<app-id>').
```

This is this project's first deployment. I am using the app.yaml from the getting started repo, nodejs runtime.

Comment: Is the `app_id=u'<app-id>'` text literally what was displayed or did you replaced your actual app-id when posting?

Comment: Are you authenticated with the correct account?

Comment: App ID stripped, authed with correct account.

Comment: Got past this error magically, still not sure what happened.